# How to save active tkinter canvas as a png file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, png

This code generates random colorful triangles or rectangles and displays them on tkinter canvas. This part of the code is working perfectly.

However, what I want is to save this random picture displayed as a png file. I have tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code :

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
from random import randint, randrange
from PIL import ImageGrab as IG


# Create random composite image.

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
COUNT = 40

# Use datetime (somehow), to generate random int.
def datetimeToInt(): 
  y, m, d, hour, min, sec = datetime.now().timetuple()[0:6]
  return y + m + d + hour + min + sec

def randRgb(): 
  x=(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
  return x

def randTriangle():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x3, y3 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]

def randRect():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)]
  return
for i in range(2):

    randEllipse = randRect

    # Map: random shape creation functions -> ImageDraw methods
    shapeFactories = [
      (randTriangle, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon),
      (randRect, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle)    ]
    shapeFactoriesCount = len(shapeFactories)

    composite = Image.new('RGBA', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), '#00000000')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(composite)
    for x in range(COUNT):
      # Get random index, within full range:
      #randIdx = randrange(0, shapeFactoriesCount)
      # Use random int, generated from datetime (somehow):
      randIdx = datetimeToInt() % shapeFactoriesCount
      shapeFactory, drawMethod = shapeFactories[randIdx]
      
      drawMethod(  # passing 'self'/'draw' explicitly to method:
        draw, shapeFactory(), fill=randRgb()
      )

    # The rest is just for displaying the resulting images.
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    compositeTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(composite)
    tk.Label(image=compositeTk).pack()

    ############

    cv=Canvas(root)
    cv.pack()
    
    image1 = Image.new("RGB", (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

    filename = "my_drawing.jpg"
    image1.save(filename)

    ############
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _" I have tried several things but nothing seems to work."_ - what have you tried?

Comment: using cv=Canvas(root)

Comment: and then cv.pack()

Comment: well, I am a beginner so, please don't mind if these things aren't correct

Comment: I also tried saving it as .ps file but that too didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating image in the end with PIL, try saving composite directly with cv2.

Try using this code

```
composite=np.uint8(composite)
cv2.imwrite(filename, composite)
```

Do import numpy and cv2 before using it.
Feel free to aske me in case of any issue.

Comment: but I can't upvote as l have a low reputation. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thats fine. Glad to know that it helped you.